# Python: Regex to strip a pattern from the word and print the rest

Tags: python, regex

Suppose there is this line of text:

> SUBSTR(name,1,20) first_name, last_name, name

I want to print the entire line excluding `SUBSTR(name,1,20)`. I want to use regular expression for this but I'm stuck because I don't understand regex.

I wrote a piece just for SUBSTR but it doesn't work.

```
import re
x="SUBSTR Hi"
func= re.sub("\bSUBSTR\b","",x)
f=x.strip()
print(f)
```

It prints the entire x value instead of just Hi. 
How to remove `SUBSTR(name,1,20)`? I don't want to use strip directly like `x.strip(SUBSTR(name,1,20)` because I will further have several patterns to write.

Comment: Did i understand correctly, you want to delete _SUBSTR_ from variable _x_?

Comment: `re.sub(r"([A-Z]+\(.*?\))", "", s).strip()` ?

Comment: Add please what answer do you expect.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\bSUBSTR\b","",x)` - Add `r` in front of string to make it "raw". Otherwise `\b` gets interpreted as normal escape sequence, not regex special sequence.

Comment: @Aurieli yes I tried for SUBSTR but I want for this SUBSTR(name,1,20) i.e, there can be any digitd or text in pace of name,1 and 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strip a specific pattern with optional followed non-whitespace sequence:

```
import re

s = 'SUBSTR(name,1,20) first_name, last_name, name'
res = re.sub(r'\bSUBSTR[^\s]*', '', s)
print(res)   #  first_name, last_name, name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern `(\b[A-Z]+\(.*?\))` in `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "SUBSTR(name,1,20) first_name, last_name, name"
print(re.sub(r"(\b[A-Z]+\(.*?\))", "", s).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
first_name, last_name, name
```

Comment: It will work, for example, with STR(name,1,20). I think it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**REGEX:** `(\b(SUBSTR)+\(.*?,.*?,.*?\))`

```
import re

s = "SUBSTR(name,1,20) first_name, last_name, name"
print(re.sub(r"(\b(SUBSTR)+\(.*?,.*?,.*?\))", "", s).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
first_name, last_name, name
```

The pattern delete part of string that starts with *SUBSTR* and everything that stays after it in *()*. If there is *()* then there must be three values with delimeter **','**. It will not delete, for example, `SUBSTR()`, because there is no input values. If it must be deleted use `\b(SUBSTR)+\(.*?\))` instead.